# Vendors.js has a large file size on build

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I started a project with Nuxt.js using `npx nuxt-create-app` and adding the following when prompted:

- Vuetify.js
- Axios
- PWA

After the command finished I ran `npm run generate` and got the output below:

```
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 50481ms
Built at: 03/22/2020 3:50:44 AM
                         Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
../server/client.manifest.json     14 KiB          [emitted]
       347edfc8c71f21607d82.js   19.3 KiB       2  [emitted] [immutable]         pages_index
       36edf39aed940985958a.js    169 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]         commons.app
       8a4f26db9171c6d3e52c.js    4.3 KiB       6  [emitted] [immutable]
       955eec4fff786128890e.js   2.35 KiB       4  [emitted] [immutable]         runtime
                      LICENSES  389 bytes          [emitted]
       a8167919c00ee96e3ace.js  817 bytes       3  [emitted] [immutable]         pages_inspire
       b80f759242c3c8480088.js    405 KiB       5  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors.app
       b8dd601015ecae11904a.js     49 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]         app
     icons/icon_120.5f6a36.png   4.68 KiB          [emitted]
     icons/icon_144.5f6a36.png    5.8 KiB          [emitted]
     icons/icon_152.5f6a36.png    6.1 KiB          [emitted]
     icons/icon_192.5f6a36.png   7.83 KiB          [emitted]
     icons/icon_384.5f6a36.png   18.1 KiB          [emitted]
     icons/icon_512.5f6a36.png     20 KiB          [emitted]
      icons/icon_64.5f6a36.png   2.35 KiB          [emitted]
        manifest.47b2f596.json  810 bytes          [emitted]
 + 2 hidden assets
Entrypoint app = 955eec4fff786128890e.js 36edf39aed940985958a.js b80f759242c3c8480088.js b8dd601015ecae11904a.js

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  b80f759242c3c8480088.js (405 KiB)
```

I changed `nuxt.conf.js` to split the files:

```
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */

   analyze: true,
    extend (config, {isClient}) {
      if (isClient){
        config.optimization.splitChunks.maxSize = 200000;
      }
    }
  }
```

But what I'm wondering is

1. Wouldn't a client still have to download the total file size even if the files are smaller? So how 
   does code splitting help?
2. What can I do, besides code splitting, to reduce the overall size since this is just the skeleton for 
   my project and it's already so large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing these 2 stragies would drastically reduce the load times.

**Suggestions:**

1. Minify and Compress the bundles with gzip/brotli compression. This will drastically reduce the bundle size. ([checkout this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-compress))
2. Route Based / Component based code splitting(I used this in React Projects)

**Answers:**

1. Yes. but if you compress it and its code splitted, its fetched only when it is required.
2. Read ***Suggestion 1***.